# Incorrect C++ runtime components

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a vs 2008 c++x32  build and when I tried to run it on a fresh windows 7 vm install, I get the following error:

> "WINDOWS 7 error The application has failed to start because the side
>   by side configuration is incorrect please see the application event
>   log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

I have found the following resolution:

> The machine is missing the correct C++ runtime components for your
>   type of system. (x86 or x64). Installing the following update resolves
>   the issue. Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)

As details about the  vs 2008 solutions: i use unicode, I don't use ATL or MFC just  Standard Windows Libraries.

My question is: am I doing something wrong? is this normal or there is a way of overcoming this problem from the development phase. What must I do so that my program would run the first time.

Comment: So... did you install the redistributable package? Did it solve the problem?

Comment: No I didn't because I am asking myself if there is a way not to need to install it

Comment: All programs compiled from Visual Studio needs a runtime library (the library that actually contains the functions used by `new`, `delete` and other runtime support functions). This runtime library needs to be there when you run your program. Either by you installing the shared libraries, or by you making your project a statically linked project so the runtime is linked to your program.

Comment: I try to make the build as minimal as possible

Comment: How do you statically link the runtime to your program? what am I missing to include my project?

Comment: YES! @JoachimPileborg, your comment answers my question, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: While you can compile an application using *"just Standard Windows Libraries"* you will usually also use the CRT (C RunTime). This is part of Visual Studio (available as a redistributable) and not a Windows component. You will have to ship the CRT alongside your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All programs compiled from Visual Studio needs a runtime library (the library that actually contains the functions used by new, delete and other runtime support functions). This runtime library needs to be there when you run your program. Either by you installing the shared libraries, or by you making your project a statically linked project so the runtime is linked to your program.